# Is it possible to format a number using the Current Culture settings but show 0 as blank?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, currency

I would like to display currency amounts (in cells of a DataGridView) using the current culture settings as defined by System.Globalisation.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat except, I do not want zero values to appear - i.e. I want them to be left blank

So, I want to know if it possible to combine the following two approaches to displaying values:

```
string.format("{0:c}", 1)  // will show $1.00 on a machine with typical English (US) settings
```

BUT;

```
string.format("{0:c}", 0)  // will show $0.00 on a machine with typical English (US) settings
```

I understand I can achieve what I want using;

```
string.format("{0:"$##,##0.00";($##,##0.00);''}", 0)
```

however as I understand it this will not be sensitive to cultural settings.

It is possible to achieve both and if so, how?

I am searching for a solution that can be implemented, in the best case by setting the format property of a DataGridViewCell and thereby allowing the DataGridView to take care of all the formatting for me. Maybe I need to subclass that cell type and override something...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom format provider and then use it for the Format property.
This should help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx#Y990

Comment: Are you able to specify the format of zeros independently when creating a custom format provider? I glanced quickly at this and could only see options for positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "";
if(amount != 0){
    s = string.Format("{0:c}", amount);
}
```

Comment: Yeh, that would do it. Sorry I didn't really give enough context in the question though.  As I'm showing the values in a cell of a DataGridView, which may even be bound at some stage, I was after a solution that didn't involve inspecting each value before loading the cell. I"m hoping to set the Format property to something magical at this stage.

Comment: Create an extension for the above logic.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
CultureInfo cinfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
cinfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
```

Now you have the required modifications made in the CultureInfo class, Now assign this `CultureInfo` back to the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` and you should be good to go

**EDIT**
This would help you in suppressing zero

```
string.Format("{0}{1:#.#}", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, value);
```

Comment: @fiver Sorry i misunderstood it for the zeros after the decimal point, will try to post an alternative. nonetheless Thanks